# yii2 query on 2 tables to return a grid view result

Tags: php, yii2

i am new to yii2 and want to do a simple query on 2 tables according to 
`policy_id`.

The result is according to `user_id` on `policyread` table. The `policyread` table holds all policies already read by the user. I am trying to show a result of all unread policies. My controllers are `PolicyController` and `PolicyreadController`. I am from old oscom 2.3.4 days and trying to learn this new framework.

Comment: cant guess anything you should add the respective models in your question so that the problem et more clear and you get appropriate replies

Comment: sorry working froma mobile phone.  the 2 models are Policy and Policyread.  i am using grid view on index.php .. policy has a hasMany relationship on policy_id and Policyread model has a hasOne relationship.

Comment: no issues Scot just add the code whenever you get time or get to your computer do update the question and add all the details in the question rather than adding in comments, just add the **EDIT** heading in the end of the question and add more info

Comment: and also add the respective `searchModel` that you are using to list the gridview.

Comment: the old style sql is .. SELECT (*) FROM policy p, policyread pr LEFTJOIN ON p.policy_id = pr.policy_id WHERE pr.user_id =  'user_id ORDER BY p.policy_id .  ive been reading but not getting very far.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out.  in my sleep deprived state i was asking for the query to return where user_idis equal .. i simply called a list of all policies then compared that array result with the user_id array of completed policies.  in the end array_diff didnt work because i was using a mulidimesnional array .. instead array_diff_key gave me the answer.  thanx again for muhammad for being patient. im a bit new here